# Retrieve in Laravel Blade data of external api

Tags: php, laravel, api

```
 public function RetrieveStatus()
    {
        $response = Http::get('https://exemple.exemple.com/fr/api/<Token>/availability/<Id>/getStatusDetails?format=json');
        $data = json_decode($response->body(), true);
        dd($data);
        return view('ControlmAPI.netvigie', [
            'data' => $data
        ]);
```

The DD of this request is :

[image: here].

So i want to retrieve the "Ok" from the request in my blade but i don't know how to do can you help me please ?

Comment: You can get 'Ok' in ```$data[0]['status']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the array and get "ok" by simply typing `{{ $data[0]['status'] }}` in your blade view.